# CRUD operations too slow after shutting down one node

Tags: cassandra

I have an application where we use cassandra database. I have a three node cluster where I am shutting down one of the nodes entirely and then my application has to send update operations for a certain set of objects. When all three nodes are up and running this takes less than one minute; however, If I am shutting down one of the nodes they are taking almost an hour.

The replication factor is set to three and consistency level is set to one.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the very little information, my guess is that your query is the problem. An `UPDATE` taking "less than one minute" is very suspicious because that's not normal.

But without all the details, there's really not much anyone here can do to help you. You really need to provide relevant details that would help others here understand your situation.

Things you should include are the table schema, sample query, steps to replicate the problem. Otherwise, all we can do is guess.

If you need help with asking questions, have a look at the guide I published at the Apache Cassandra website on [How to ask good questions](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/community/ask_good_questions.html). Cheers!